# Can I add text inputs to a Matlab function in Simulink?

Tags: string, matlab, simulink

In Simulink, I know how to define a Matlab function that takes a constant or signal as input and processes it. I would like to ask if there is also a possibility to input a (constant) string to a Matlab function. I looked in the *library browser* and cannot find a block that can represent a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulink [does not support chars](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/data-types-supported-by-simulink.html). Easiest work around is a constant block with the value `uint8('hello world')`. In your MatlabFunction Block you can convert it back to text using `char(varname)`.